# Regex to match a constant number within a number in HTML

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regex in an html pattern attribute to match the `input(type="number")`

1. The length should be 16 digits
2. The first 5 digits should be exactly 11995

I've tried `([11995]+[0-9])` but it's not working.

Any help with this will be highly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A sequence of numbers when written inside a square brackets means a single character and any character contained within those square brackets. Hence, `[11995]` means either `1` or `9` or `5`. The correct way to write that regex would be this,

`\b11995[0-9]{11}\b` in case you want to match such numbers in  larger text

OR

`^11995[0-9]{11}$` in case you want to match the number as whole.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The second option is what I've been looking for!

Answer (score 1):

`11995\d{11}` will match 11995, and then 11 more digits afterwards. `\b11995\d{11}\b` asserts it is followed on both sides by a "word boundary", and `^11995\d{11}$` asserts it is the only thing in the string. These can be easily modified to match other delimiters, such as `"` or `<>`.

[Try it here!](https://regex101.com/r/9PALXz/1/)